# Get only folder names in a directory, skipping dots and ignoring certain folders

Tags: php, iterator, directory-structure

I need to get only the folder names in a directory. So far I found the DirectoryIterator to be useful. However I am not getting the desired names of the folders.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname($directory));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {

    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
        if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        //echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . '<br>';
        }    
    }    
}
```

**Please see**: I also want to skip the dots (**.**) and (**..**) 
while having the ability to ignore folders I choose.

Comment: doesn't `!$fileinfo->isDot()` already skip the `.` and `..` ??

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that part is intentional. It's part of my solution. However as a whole it does not seem to work. Anyway I have come up with an alternate solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
$path = 'PATH';

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        //skips dots  
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;
        //ignore folders
        if ('FOLDER_TO_IGNORE' === $file) continue;

        //check if filename is a folder
        if (is_dir($file)){
        //DO SOMETHING WITH FOLDER ($file)
        }

    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```